# Entropy difference dominance of sequences

Tags: entropy, nonlinear-optimization

Consider a collection of positive integers $\{a_i\}_{i=1}^m$ and the distribution $p_i=\frac{a_i}{\sum_{i=1}^ma_i}$.

Similarly for the collection $\{a_i\}_{i=1}^{m+1}$ form the distribution $q_i=\frac{a_i}{\sum_{i=1}^{m+1}a_i}$, for the collection $\{a_i\}_{i=1}^{n}$ form the distribution $r_i=\frac{a_i}{\sum_{i=1}^{n}a_i}$ and for the collection $\{a_i\}_{i=1}^{n+1}$ form the distribution $s_i=\frac{a_i}{\sum_{i=1}^{n+1}a_i}$.

Let $m+1\leq n$. Note all collections are subsets of the collection for the distribution $s$.

For the cases $(1)$ $a_{i+1}=a_i+\theta(\log^ka_i)$, $(2)$ $a_{i+1}=a_i+\theta(a_i)$ where $k$ is a postive constant,  is it true that the difference in entropy is strictly decreasing? That is, is $H(q)-H(p)>H(s)-H(r)$ valid? When can one expect difference in Shannon entropy to be dominant in sequences of these types? Clearly in this post [Entropy dominance](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/191391/entropy-dominance), one criteria for negative result is given. Can $a_i$ be any larger or smaller than in the cases given?

---

Can we guess $\lim_{n\rightarrow\infty}H(s)=\infty$ in all these cases?

What spacing in $a_i$ would guarantee $\lim_{n\rightarrow\infty}H(s)<c\in\Bbb N$?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's some examplary evidence that maybe the answers are Yes.

- For Case 2, let $a_{i+1}=2a_i$ for all $i$ with $a_1=1$.
  Then the binary entropy is
  $$
  -\frac1{2^{n}-1} \sum_{k=0}^{n-1} 2^k \log_2\left(\frac{2^k}{2^{n}-1}\right)$$
  $$
  \approx-\frac1{2^{n}} \sum_{k=0}^{n-1} 2^k \log_2\left(\frac{2^k}{2^{n}}\right)$$
  $$
  =\sum_{k=0}^{n-1} \frac{n-k}{2^{n-k}}=\frac{2^{n+1}-n-2}{2^n}\nearrow 2$$
  which is the entropy of the geometric distribution with parameter $1/2$. So it seems that in this case yes, the difference in entropy is decreasing.
  A similar calculation woks if $a_{i+1}=u\cdot a_i$ for a positive integer $u>2$.
- For Case 1, well let's go all the way to the extreme case $a_i=1$ for all $i$. In this case the entropy is just $\log n$ and so by concavity of log, yes, the difference in entropy is decreasing.

Comment: Converges from below

Comment: Actually can we still guess that $H(s)\rightarrow\infty$ always as $n\rightarrow\infty$? This is not very clear.

Comment: No, the entropy of the geometric distribution with parameter 1/2 is 2 not infinity

Comment: Thank you. I am looking for classifying distributions of the above type with finite and infinite entropy. I looked at http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Geometric_distribution and looked at the exact formula. It looks like geom distribution does not work. Anything else could help classify among the case 1 and 2?

Comment: If we start with $a_1=4$. For $k=2$ in case $2$ we get $4,6,6+\log^2 6,6+2\log^2 6+\log^2(1+\frac{\log^2 6}{6}),\dots$ and it seems the distributions remain more or less 'close' to uniform and hence it looks like entropy should be $\infty$. For case $2$, we see the sequence $4,8,16,32,\dots$ and it looks like there will more weight to the probabilities associated with new $a_i$s. Entropy here too looks like it will go to $\infty$. Looks like I need to post another question. Shall I do that posts?

Comment: No it looks like for case $2$, $4,8,16,32,\dots$ case, the distribution approaches geometric with parameter $\frac{1}{2}$. Correct about this distribution assessment?

Comment: Yes if I understood you correctly

Comment: So for case $1$ entropy is infinite for all finite $k$?

Comment: Another good question. .. maybe post it as such?

Comment: Addedhttp://mathoverflow.net/questions/191678/limiting-entropy-of-deterministic-sequences

Comment: http://mathoverflow.net/questions/191678/limiting-entropy-of-deterministic-‌​sequences

Comment: Does the new questions have difficult answers?