# Limiting Entropy of deterministic sequences - 1

Tags: entropy, nonlinear-optimization

Consider a collection of increasing positive integers $\{a_i\}_{i=1}^m$.

Consider distribution $p_i=\frac{a_i}{\sum_{i=1}^ma_i}$. Given $\{a_i\}_{i=1}^m$, let $\mathcal{P}_{a,m}$ be distribution at every $m$.

$$\mbox{Case }(1)\mbox{: }a_{i+1}=a_i+\theta(\log^ka_i)$$ 
$$\mbox{Case }(2)\mbox{: }a_{i+1}=a_i+\theta(a_i^{\frac{1}{k}})$$ where $k$ is a positive constant.

$\mathsf{\underline{Conjecture}}$: I think at a fixed $k>0$, there will be constants $c_k>0, m(a,c_k)\in\Bbb N$ such that: $$\mbox{Case }1\mbox{: }\forall m>m(a,c_k)\mbox{, }H(\mathcal{P}_{a,m})>c_k$$ $$\mbox{Case }2\mbox{: }\forall m>0\mbox {,            }H(\mathcal{P}_{a,m})<c_k.$$

Follow from relevant link [Entropy difference dominance of sequences](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/191438/entropy-difference-dominance-of-sequences)

Generalization is in here [Limiting Entropy of deterministic sequences - 2](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/191683/limiting-entropy-of-deterministic-sequences-2)

Comment: Added http://mathoverflow.net/questions/191683/limiting-entropy-of-deterministic-sequences-2

Comment: I don't quite understand your setup. What do you mean by the limiting distribution $\mathcal P_a$? Since your sequence $a_i$ is increasing, for any fixed $i$ the limit of $a_i/\sum_{i=1}^m a_i$ is $0$ for $m\to\infty$. However later on you are asking whether $H(\mathcal P_a)\to\infty$ apparently presuming that $\mathcal P_a$ depends on something else.

Comment: @RW Idea is at each $m$, sequence $\{a\}^m_{i=1}$ has entropy $H(a,m)$. I am questioning about growth of $H(a,m)$ as a function of $m$ (is there a path to make it more precise here?)

Comment: @RW Does update make more sense?

Comment: Yes - now it's clear what you are asking about

Answer (score 1):

Regarding (2), the answer seems to be *no* by the reasoning at [Entropy difference dominance of sequences](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/191438/entropy-difference-dominance-of-sequences)
That is, the limiting entropy can be that of the geometric distribution, which is finite.

The boundary between finite and infinite entropy may be close to a distribution like $p_1,\dots,p_m$ where $p_k$ is on the order of
$$
\frac1{k(\log k)^a},\quad a\in\{2,3\}.
$$
Because then the entropy will be
$$
\sum_k \frac{-1}{k(\log k)^a}\cdot\log\left(\frac{1}{k(\log k)^a}\right)$$
$$
=\sum_k \frac{\log k+a\log\log k}{k(\log k)^a}\approx \sum_k \frac{1}{k(\log k)^{a-1}}
$$
which goes to infinity as $m\rightarrow\infty$ if $a=2$, but not if $a=3$.

Comment: $a=2$ case corresponds to $a_{i+1}=a_i + \theta(\log^c a_i)$ correct for all fixed $c\geq2$ correct? What does $a=3$ case correspond to in terms of $|a_{i+1}-a_i|$?

Comment: I didn't check how it covers the case (1) exactly, so maybe you can try to work it out and report back

Comment: I checked a while back. Case $1$ seems related to $a\leq2$ and case $2$ seems related to $a>2$(possibly $a$ takes value such as $3$ that makes your summation converge).

Comment: @BjornKjosHanssen What is interpretation of entropy here? Does it mean we should be able to compress $a_i$ in finite number of bits or impossible to do in finite number of bits in total?

Comment: @Turbo sounds like another interesting question :)

Comment: Posted http://mathoverflow.net/questions/191943/interpretation-of-shannon-entropy-application

Comment: So in this question am I right in my conjecture?