# Limiting Entropy of deterministic sequences - 2

Tags: nonlinear-optimization, entropy

Consider a collection of increasing positive integers $\{a_i\}_{i=1}^m$ and the distribution $p_i=\frac{a_i}{\sum_{i=1}^ma_i}$. Given $\{a_i\}_{i=1}^m$, let $\mathcal{P}_a$ be limiting distribution $m\rightarrow\infty$.

For a given $c>0$, what spacing in $a_i$ would guarantee $H(\mathcal{P}_a)<c$?

What is precise growth of $H(\mathcal{P}_a)$ as a function of gaps of sequences?

Follow from relevant link [Limiting Entropy of deterministic sequences - 1](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/191678/limiting-entropy-of-deterministic-sequences-1)